# Unresolved Reference: Fragment_gallery Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase, android-layout, android-fragment, firebase-auth

Buenas estuve intentando compilar una aplicación extremadamente sencilla que encontre en youtube, el código es muy similar al del creador del contenido por lo que descarto la sintaxis del código que yo hubiera escrito. A continuación anexo el código donde se me presenta el error.

GalleryFragment ERROR EN: "fragment_gallery" y "text_gallery"

```
@file:Suppress("DEPRECATION")

package com.example.pccontroller.ui.gallery


import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.example.pccontroller.R
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment


@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class GalleryFragment() : Fragment(), Parcelable {

  private lateinit var galleryViewModel: GalleryViewModel

  constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this()

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View? {
    galleryViewModel =
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel::class.java)
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.fragment_gallery, container, false)
    val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery)
    galleryViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
      textView.text
    })
    return root
  }

  override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {

  }

  override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
  }

  companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<GalleryFragment> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): GalleryFragment {
      return GalleryFragment(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<GalleryFragment?> {
      return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
  }
}
```

HomeFragment ERROR EN: "fragment_home" y "text_home"

```
@file:Suppress("DEPRECATION")

package com.example.pccontroller.ui.home

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.example.pccontroller.R


@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

  private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View? {
    homeViewModel =
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
    homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
      textView.text = it
    })
    return root
  }
}
```

SlideshowFragment ERROR EN: "fragment_slideshow" y "text_slideshow"

```
@file:Suppress("DEPRECATION")

package com.example.pccontroller.ui.slideshow

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.example.pccontroller.R

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class SlideshowFragment : Fragment() {

  private lateinit var slideshowViewModel: SlideshowViewModel

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    slideshowViewModel =
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SlideshowViewModel::class.java)
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slideshow, container, false)
    val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_slideshow)
    slideshowViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
      textView.text = it
    })
    return root
  }
}
```

Como se que puede ser de utilidad anexo los códigos con las dependencias de gradle.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Y

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pccontroller"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:19.3.1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"


    def fragment_version = "1.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

En la clase GalleryFragment estas inflando un layout pero no estas especificando el directorio donde se encuentra, solo especificas `R.fragment_gallery` lo cual es incorrecto y por esa razon no encuentra la referencia que deseas:

```
  val root = inflater.inflate(R.fragment_gallery, container, false)
   val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery)
```

especifica el directorio layout y asegura que en el layout `fragment_gallery.xml` se encuentre en ese directorio y contenga el TextView con id `text_gallery`:

```
  val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false)
  val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery)
```

---

Los layouts deben agregarse en el directorio layout:

[image: ,]

Comment: La verdad es que en la carpeta layout no se encuentran dichos archivos .xml ni el del fragment_gallery, ni los otros dos que presentan el error. En ese caso procede generarlo manualmente, o estoy buscando en el directorio incorrecto. 

Muchas gracias por la respuesta :)

Comment: Unresolved reference significa que no puede encontrar el recurso o clase, si no existe entonces hay que agregarlo Jorge.

Comment: Para crearlo le dos alt+may+enter y ya, o debo agregar algo donde de él ?

Comment: Debes agregar el layout dentro del directorio layout, agregue una imagen.